# Is it possible to use GridGain file system with storage other than Hadoop

Tags: gridgain

Is there an way to use the GridGain in-memory file system on top of storage other than the Hadoop file system?

Actually my idea it would to use just like a cache on top of a plain file system or shared NFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GridGain chose Hadoop [FileSystem](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) API as the secondary file system interface. So, the answer is Yes, as long as you wrap another file system into Hadoop [FileSystem](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) interface.

Also, you may wish to look at [HDFS NFS Gateway](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsNfsGateway.html) project.

Comment: Ok, I see. In the case I go for implementing the Hadoop FileSystem interface, what version I should use 0.2.x, 1.x or 2.x? I mean, what version are you supporting/implementing? Best

Comment: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem is binary and API-compatible across Hadoop versions (the only change between 1.x and 2x is that some methods got deprecated): GridGain works both with Hadoop 1.x and 2.x through this API. It should not make any difference which version you will choose.